# How to make my hyperlink remain as it is even when hovered over it?

Tags: html, css

I have requirement where I have a logout icon and when I hover over it, it is getting dimmed. I dont want that to happen. It should remain as it is even when I hover over it. I have also used `text-decoration:none` but it is still not working.

Here is my code.

```
<a data-ng-click="logout()" class="fa fa-sign-out font-icon-size"></a>

.fa {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

a, a:hover, a:link {
    color: #1F6689;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: May be `.fa` has hover effect. Inspect it and solve it.

Comment: @ Bhojendra Nepal. There is hover effect in my .fa

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal How do I override?

Comment: post the code for .fa:hover css.

Comment: Yes I tried that. .fa:hover{text-decoration:none;}. Its still not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103170/discussion-between-shruthi-sathyanarayana-and-bhojendra-nepal).

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana why dont you remove hover style.

Comment: @VIVEKRAJ I still see no difference.

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana can you give the link. or code snippet in jsfiddle.